# How to get back-reference variables in multiple RewriteCond with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

These rewrite rules don't seem to work. Is it just not possible or am I missing something

The problematic rule is the second one, notice the back-reference %1

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z\.]+)/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} route_controller_%1=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com/%1/_/$1 [L]
```

This is what I am expecting to happen. Given the URL

```
http://example.com/abc/home
```

The first rule should store abc in %1
I want the second rule for a cookie called route_controller_abc and if found
Then the third rule would rewite to

```
http://example2.com/thevalueofthecookie/_/home
```

But the seconf rule doesn't seem to be using the %1 back-reference.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that string substitution only occurs in the first parameter on a cond and not on its rexexp.  You have to do a hack to simulate parameters in regexps using `\1` etc.

You can also pick up the directory in the rule regexp, since the execution order is rule regexp, cond1, cond2,... rule substitution. eg. `^(*.?)/.*$` for `abc/home`will set `$1` to `abc` and $0 to `abc/home`.  Hence I would try something like:

```
RewriteCond $1:%{HTTP_COOKIE} ^(.*?):.*\broute_controller_\1=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(*.?)/.*$        http://example2.com/%2/_/$0            [L]
```

Note that the controller is now in %2 as %1 is used to bind the directory in the cond regexp.

Hope this helps and answers your direct Q.  Hovever, I would be a little twitchy using unvalidated cookies like this for redirection.  If I were doing this I would either tighten the validation of the parameter `([^;]+)` or move this to a small PHP redirector script and do the validation there :-)

Comment: Ok I'll give it a whirl. Regarding unvalidated cookies for redirection. I was planning on having my app at example2.com doing the validation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, using an app to do it is fine, but remember that a malicious user can always edit cookies, so you can have no trust in their content.  The user could just about inject anything into `%2`.  So if you know this is a plain word, for example, then why not `(\w+)` which would effectively prevent malicious injections?

Comment: I am not expecting a plain word but rather a Fully qualified domain name. By the way I was not able to get the rules to work on my system as written. In the RewriteCond I changed $1 to %1. In the RewriteRule I changed `^(*.?)/.*$` to `^(.*)$` I was getting an Internal Server Error with the RewriteRule.

Comment: sounds like you didn't get rid of the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` line.